# Editing a 10gb file using limited main memory in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, sorting, file-io

I need to sort a 10gb file containing a list of numbers as fast as possible using only 100mb of memory.
I'm breaking them into chunks and then merging them.

I am currently using C File pointers as they go faster than c++ file i/o(atleast on my system).

I tried for a 1gb file and my code works fine, but it throws a segmentation fault as soon as I fscanf after opening the 10gb file.

```
FILE *fin;
FILE *fout;
fin = fopen( filename, "r" );
while( 1 ) {
    // throws the error here
    for( i = 0; i < MAX && ( fscanf( fin, "%d", &temp ) != EOF ); i++ ) {
        v[i] = temp;
    }
```

What should I use instead?

And do you have any suggestions about how to go about this in the best way possible?

Comment: What are `v` and `MAX`? That is, are you trying to allocate an array larger than you really can? Are you writing past the end of an array?

Comment: v is my array which is dynamically allocated.
MAX is a macro.
v is defined as int v = new int[MAX];
And MAX is much smaller than what can be..

Comment: You're going to have to use APIs that support "large files". Which you use may depend on your operating system, but the C stdio APIs don't necessary support large enough offset types to deal with files of that size. It is generally possible, but you're likely going to need to share more information about your platform to get a useful answer.

Comment: did you check the allocation for null pointers? also relevant might be your platform (architecture+os), eg it might be necessary to set `-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64`

Comment: I'm using a 32bit Linux, Ubuntu to be specific, compiling using g++.

Comment: You are not checking if fopen failed or succeeded.  fopen returns null if it fails, so you need to check for fin == null, and if that is true, check errno to see why the open failed.  fin == null is the most likely reason for the segfault. 

This you have two questions here: why is this code segfaulting, and what is the best way to sort a list that is larger than main memory?

Comment: You may want to read the book "Programming Pearls".

Comment: Stupid question, but isn't `sort` able to deal with external sorting ?

Comment: @mch: Yes what you said is true.
I added the line and it exits there, so what do you suggest?

Comment: Re. use APIs that support large files. I have experience with this and the simplest approach can be to minimise the APIs used in the first place. On Linux that might mean sticking to plain old read() and write().

Comment: @Christoph - Can you expand a little? Where do I set that flag ?

Comment: @Skkard: see http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Feature-Test-Macros.html for details; passing in `-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64` as a compiler flag to gcc/g++ will use the 64-bit versions of file IO with the default names; as an alternative, add `#define _LARGEFILE_SOURCE` and `#define _LARGEFILE64_SOURCE` at the top of your source file and explicitly use the 64-bit versions (eg `off64_t`, `fseeko64`, ...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a special class of algorithms for this called *external sorting*. There is a variant of *merge sort* that is an external sorting algorithm (just google for *merge sort tape*).

But if you're on Unix, it's probably easier to run the *sort* command in a separate process.

BTW. Opening files that are bigger than 2 GB requires large file support. Depending on your operating system and your libraries, you need to define a macro or call other file handling functions.